# На vba(word) выводиться весь текст из документа, а нужно лишь строки которые содержат как минимум 2 вхождения «нн»

Tags: регулярные-выражения, vba

```
Sub f()
    Dim regex As Object
    Dim res As Object
    Dim s As Object
    

    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With regex
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .Pattern = "^.*нн.*нн.*$"
    End With
    Set res = regex.Execute(ActiveDocument.Range.Text)
    
    
    For Each s In res
        MsgBox s
    Next
End Sub
```

Выводиться вообще всё, а необходимо только слова которые подходят условию.

Comment: Потому что именно всё и запрошено... Вы же не отдельные строки текста тестируете, а весь текст как единое целое... весь текст - соответствует, вот он и выводится. Так что надо разделить текст на строки, потом в цикле тестировать каждую строку, и выводить только соответствующие шаблону.

Comment: А как именно это нужно сделать? Я не гений так что сорри

Comment: Да я почём знаю... опубликованное задание допускает кучу разных интерпретаций. например, что есть "строка"? элементарно - это физическое понятие или визуальное?

Comment: Точка это любой символ в том числе пробел, вместо точки используйте \w например

Comment: @4per Задание не ограничивает местоположение указанного фрагмента. Может, там строки вообще случайные наборы букв..

Comment: А ну да, тогда скорее всего проблема из-за жадности выражения, нужен ленивый вариант. Вообщем сайт regex1001 в помощь

Comment: А что сейчас на VBA делают?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub f()
    Dim regex As Object, res As Object, s As String

    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With regex
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .MultiLine = True
        
        .Pattern = "[^\s,]*нн[^\s,]*"
        Set res = .Execute(ActiveDocument.Range.Text)
    End With
    
    If res.Count > 0 Then
        For Each r In res
            s = s & r & vbLf
        Next
        MsgBox s
    End If
End Sub
```

Более-менее приличный справочник по [VBScript.RegExp](http://script-coding.com/WSH/RegExp.html#4.)

Comment: Я совсем забыл сказать что результат нужно вывести в виде Message Box. Я меняю Debug.Print на Message Box и мне просто выдаёт ошибку. А так всё работает. И нужно не просто "нн", а слово целиком. Извини конечно что я сразу не сказал, я просто совсем забыл

Comment: Выводиться вообще всё я хз как это исправить.